I was hired because of my experience and expertise (I thought), but I was assigned another job upon joining and it lasts forever. Should I leave?
Before I joined, I had multiple conversations with the then hiring manager to plan my role and responsibilities more concretely (the initial JD was very vague and the hiring manager was persistent in pursuing me). My work proposals were appreciated by the then hiring manager, then I was reassured to just join and everything would be "flexible and possible". I was also told that I was "overqualified", which I didn't quite understand why back then. It was at a time I went through a personal injury and loss and was in grief. I wasn't thinking clearly and went with it and accepted the job offer.
After I joined, my assignment, from day one, has not been what I envisaged and proposed. I was remote, not quick to know what was going on, but I soon realized what I proposed for my role and the to-do's, were all adopted by the hiring manager to build the "team" which I later discovered I was the only one left out. I gradually watched the plans (which are from my personal experiences and endeavors over the years) were used to establish others' new roles and advancements. I have been kept uninformed and isolated on the one and only entry-level assignment, forever.
I spoke to the hiring manager about it, but I quickly found that they had been constructively shifting what I supplied to them in those unofficial conversations, to the "bigger team" which includes everyone but me. I discussed my work assignment with another manager a few times, to no avail. They heard me, they agreed with me, but no change. And what's been going on has doubled down. I had to reassess the reality. It is clearly against my professional interest and skill sets and expertise to work in a role that has low value and no growth for me. No chance to hone my skills and get to my personal next level. Over time, and in retrospect, I came to realize that I was likely hired to fill a "pit" at the time a previous pit-filler had left. And now I am the one in it. That would be what the then hiring manager meant by I was "overqualified".
Now I've been stuck in this role for 8 months, with other facts emerging over time, I know I'm pinned on to this role for good unless 1) there's a replacement in place to free me up; 2) I make big moves. By mechanically repeating something that does not require thinking for this long, I feel I'm killing myself inside. I've never had any sense of accomplishment in doing it. Being kept on this assignment makes me feel like an idiot, and treated like so. And I got a "congratulations that you will be where you are for the next two years" letter with a slight pay rise which will happen in two years. I laughed, I laughed hard.
The alarm bells rang when I suddenly realized my motivation evaporated, my momentum to actively engage in what I did really well before joining the company became hazy. I found myself lost drive to get up in the morning.
All has happened in professional settings, I secretly think I was "scammed" by the true hiring intentions I didn't know back then. None of the job responsibilities agreed before I joined is in sight. My contributions to the "bigger team" was made before I joined. My current and forever assignment after onboarding is something utterly different and 10 levels lower. I have been thinking of leave. Some around me say you can't leave a job less than a year, just keep positive, appear happy and stick it out until you find your forever employer. But I see my current job an absolutely wrong move and a great setback, I don't see any worth staying longer, let alone I start to suffer mentally from it. No challenge, no change, no growth, just labouring. I'd rather go happily unemployed than staying in such a job with pay.
Now after writing all these down, I think I've made the decision to leave against all advice to stay.
I should now revise my question - Looks like I'll go unemployed for a while. After hearing concerns from those around me, I'm a bit worried and my question is: what should I tell the potential new employers why I left and unemployed?

It seems like you answered your question already. What exactly are you asking?

Edited my question at the end. New joiner here, sorry for the confusion!

Please edit this wall of text, paragraphs will make it easier to read, remember some won't bother as it looks too daunting.

Edited it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Is this your first job?

No. I am a veteran and I led projects in previous companies.

No assignment lasts forever. No project lasts forever. The statement about the next 2 years does not mean it is impossible to be promoted or to be assigned higher level work before then. I'm not saying you're wrong to want to look elsewhere, but you may be panicking prematurely.


what should I tell the potential new employers why I left and unemployed?

The most neutral thing an outside observer could say: "Job description was vague and the actual job turned out to be something entirely different than what I've thought.".
It actually happens quite often. You seem to be unusually bitter about it. Don't show that to employers, neither future nor current. Laugh it off with "Fool me once, shame on you; fool me twice, shame on me.". You've learned the red flags, that's the experience you take from this pit.

Thanks for the feedback! What I should have made clearer in my question is that the role I found I was in, is not only different from the JD discussion, it is also a rookie's step to the area that I was already proficient in. This was simply many steps back from what I had already achieved before I joined. It is a big rollback in my career. In retrospect, that is why I was vaguely told that I was "overqualified". My mistake that I didn't listen to my instinct, but fell for it under the persistent pursuit from the hiring manager.

@user152459 That part was already clear. You are still focused on the harm done to you. That is the real danger you're in: succumbing to a grudge. It doesn't matter "how bad you were wronged". It doesn't matter if you were wronged at all. LET IT GO! Job interview is like a first date: never talk about your ex. Never think about your ex. It's been a month now. I always feel relieved when I make the decision to leave - but you don't sound relieved at all. I think this situation is taking a toll on you, I think you need counseling. Leave the past behind, or it will ruin your chances for next job.

They told you at the outset that you were overqualified. It was never going to work out.  They shouldn't have hired you. I have been refused a job 3 times in my career, where I was told that I was overqualified and they expected me to not work there for long.
Look for a job, and move away as soon as you can. Tell the prospective employers that the job was boring and not challenging for you.

I put my trust in the wrong place. Despite the red flags, I took the job due to my lapse in vigilance. Thanks for your sharing and suggestions.

Sounds like you shouldn't have taken this job in the first place, if you don't have the time and patience to work yourself into a better position internally.
Tell interviewers that, after reflection, you agreed that you were overqualified for the job you were hired into and were looking for a job where you could contribute more.
